# Difference between ProgressDialog.setProgress(value) and ProgressDialog.setMessage(message) in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I earlier used the `setProgress()` method to update the progress but now have several progresses I need to show and update so I attempted to doing it with `setMessage()`.
However when using `setMessage()` I receive the `CalledFromWrongThreadException` right after the `ProgressDialog` had been updated (like, I see it's getting updated shortly).

Here's my `onProgressUpdate` method:

```
@Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
//          progressdialog.setProgress(values[0]);
            Log.v("PDMessage", "Cycle: " + values[1] + "/" + values[2] + "\n" + "Progress: " + values[0] + "%");
            progressdialog.setMessage("Cycle: " + values[1] + "/" + values[2] + "\n" + "Progress: " + values[0] + "%");
//          updateProgressBar(values[0]);
        }
```

LogCat shows me the expected output with correct values so there's no issue with those.

**Can anyone explain to me the difference here?**
I know how to fix it (and there's already an answer down there) but I don't know why `setProgress()` doesn't request me to do it that way.

Comment: Try to write you setMessage() code inside runOnUiThread().

Comment: Ya I read about it already but I'd like to know, why I have to do it with `setMessage()` but not with `setProgress()`.

Comment: Still looking for an answer. Reminder, I don't need code. It's something I just want to understand.

Comment: Check AsyncTask various method to change progess value : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
  @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    //          progressdialog.setProgress(values[0]);
                Log.v("PDMessage", "Cycle: " + values[1] + "/" + values[2] + "\n" + "Progress: " + values[0] + "%");

 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             progressdialog.setMessage("Cycle: " + values[1] + "/" + values[2] + "\n" + "Progress: " + values[0] + "%");

            }



        }
    });
```

Comment: see his comment..once?

Comment: Thanks, I know how to fix it. But my question is, why I'm not supposed to do it the same way with the `setProgress()` method.

Comment: btw. the `Integer values` needs to be `final`